# Ruby on Rails 3 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' on OSX

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, macos

I have a standard Rails3 environment, RVM 1.2.9, Rails 3.0.5, Ruby 1.9.2p180, MySQL2 Gem 0.2.7,  mysql-5.5.10-osx10.6-x86_64

Error I get when running `rake db:migrate` to create database is:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

config/database.yml has

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: xxxx
  database: xxxx
```

sure it's something simple I'm missing.

Comment: Is the socket file present? Maybe it's present somewhere else (/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock)?

Comment: Nope, neither exist. I'll try create one.

Comment: the core of this issues or at the OS level..

Answer (score 213, accepted):

First, to find your socket file:

```
mysqladmin variables | grep socket
```

For me, this gives:

```
| socket                                            | /tmp/mysql.sock                                                                                                        |
```

Then, add a line to your `config/database.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: xxxx
  database: xxxx
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: If you have a password on root, do: "mysqladmin -pxxxx variables | grep socket" where xxxx is your root password

Comment: I'm confused about how this works; where/how do you enter in the first command you listed? When I enter that into the terminal, it reports: `mysqladmin: command not found`

Comment: You can enter the command in any folder. `Command not found` indicates you don't have mysql installed.

Comment: Even though I had no password I still  had to specify the user as root:    

mysqladmin -u root variables | grep socket

Comment: @CodeBiker FYI: Linux shells tend not to execute unqualified program names from the working directory (unless it's explicitly in the `PATH`) - you have to be explicit, e.g. `./program_name ...`.  This means that the actual program executed tends to be independent of where you try to run it from.

Comment: This answer does not address the specific database.yml file configuration the OP included.

Answer (score 91):

Found it!

Change `host: localhost` in config/database.yml to `host: 127.0.0.1` to make rails connect over TCP/IP instead of local socket.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: 127.0.0.1
  username: root
  password: xxxx
  database: xxxx
```

Comment: It would be better to find the mysql.sock file location and adding this line to config/database.yml: "socket: /path/to/mysql.sock"

Comment: What's the benefit of using a socket over TCP/IP? Sorry - I'm pretty new to Rails and Unix

Comment: Unix sockets have less overhead than TCP/IP sockets.

Comment: Thank you!  I ran into this problem outside of Rails (using mysql gem) and this solution worked.  I don't have root access so I can't modify the gem to use another location for the socket file. This trick saved me headaches.

Comment: For some reason I didn't need this in an `Ubuntu` server, but in `CentOS` I had to add it.

Comment: This answer has helped me in a different way.  I'm running my rails application against a dockerized mysql instance, with localhost 3306 exposed.  One side effect of this setup is that even though you can connect through localhost, you can only connect thought TCP since mysql is running in a VM, rather than on the same machine - so no socket connection.  In lieu of this, mandating Rails use TCP is the answer here, because sadly there doesn't seem to be a better option that I've found.

Answer (score 11):

Your mysql server may not be running. Below explains how to start the server. This is an excerpt from the README file that comes with the mysql download.

After the installation, you can start up MySQL by running the following
commands in a terminal window. You must have administrator privileges
to perform this task.

If you have installed the Startup Item, use this command:

```
 shell> sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
 (ENTER YOUR PASSWORD, IF NECESSARY)
 (PRESS CONTROL-D OR ENTER "EXIT" TO EXIT THE SHELL)
```

If you don't use the Startup Item, enter the following command sequence:

```
 shell> cd /usr/local/mysql
 shell> sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe
 (ENTER YOUR PASSWORD, IF NECESSARY)
 (PRESS CONTROL-Z)
 shell> bg
 (PRESS CONTROL-D OR ENTER "EXIT" TO EXIT THE SHELL)
```

Comment: This answer helped me fix this issue on my MAC...not sure why this comment is not ranked higher.  When you install mysql there are some notes displayed in the console.  I had to run the following commands. `unset TMPDIR` and `mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami` --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp`....then I had to start the server `mysql.server start`

Comment: It is possible for the service to stop working, this is definitely the first thing to check.

Answer (score 8):

These are options to fix this problem:

**Option 1:** change you host into 127.0.0.1

```
staging:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: 127.0.0.1
  username: root
  password: xxxx
  database: xxxx
  socket: your-location-socket
```

**Option 2:** It seems like you have 2 connections into you server MySql.
To find your socket file location do this:

```
mysqladmin variables | grep socket
```

for me gives:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!
```

or

```
mysql --help
```

I get this error because I installed XAMPP in my OS X Version 10.9.5 for PHP application. Choose one of the default socket location here.

I choose for default rails apps:

```
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

For my PHP apps, I install XAMPP so I set my socket here:

```
socket: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

**OTHERS Socket Location in OS X**

For MAMPP:

```
socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

For Package Installer from MySQL:

```
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

For MySQL Bundled with Mac OS X Server:

```
socket: /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

**For Ubuntu:**

```
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock
```

**Option 3:** If all those setting doesn't work you can remove your socket location:

```
staging:
  # socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Nice explaination this command: `socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock` worked for me

Answer (score 6):

"/tmp/mysql.sock" will be created automatically when you start the MySQL server. So remember to do that before starting the rails server.

Answer (score 3):

With my installation of MAMP on OSX the MySQL socket is located at `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`. I used `locate mysql.sock` to find my MySQL socket location.

So my `config/database.yml` looks like:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: xxxx
  database: xxxx
  socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Mac OSX,

> The default location for the MySQL Unix socket is different on Mac OS X and Mac OS X Server depending on the installation type you chose

[MySQL Unix Socket Locations on Mac OS X by Installation Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/macosx-installation-notes.html)

- Package Installer from MySQL ------------------/tmp/mysql.sock

---

- Tarball from MySQL -------------------------------/tmp/mysql.sock

---

- MySQL Bundled with Mac OS X Server -------/var/mysql/mysql.sock

So just change your ***database.yml*** in  `socket: /tmp/mysql.sock` to point to the right place depending on what OS and installation type you are using

Answer (score 2):

The default location for the MySQL socket on Mac OS X is `/var/mysql/mysql.sock`.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem, but none of the answers quite gave a step by step of what I needed to do. This error happens because your socket file has not been created yet. All you have to do is:

1. Start you mysql server, so your `/tmp/mysql.sock` is created, to do that you run: `mysql server start`
2. Once that is done, go to your app directory end edit the `config/database.yml` file and add/edit the `socket: /tmp/mysql.sock` entry
3. Run `rake:dbmigrate` once again and everything should workout fine

Comment: `rake db:migrate` *

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is that I only have a production environment. I do not have a development or test environment.

By adding 'RAILS_ENV=production' to give the command

```
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MYSQL through XAMPP:

1. Open XAMPP mysql configuration file (on OSX):

   /Applications/XAMPP/etc/my.cnf
2. Copy the socket path:

   socket      = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
3. Open rails project's database configuration file:
   myproject/config/database.yml
4. Add the socket config to the development database config:

-->

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: difiuri_falcioni
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  socket: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

5. Restart rails server

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with like this: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Ans: $ sudo service mysql start

Answer (score 0):

On my machine mysqld service stopped that's why it was giving me the same problem.

1:- Go to terminal and type

```
sudo service mysqld restart
```

This will restart the mysqld service and create a new sock file on the required location.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MYSQL through XAMPP or LAMPP on Ubuntu or other Linux, try:

`socket: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock`