# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket: I'm lost [Rails App]

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently trying to deploy my Rails 4 app to AWS, but each time I try to view the app on AWS, I get an application error.  I check the logs and see:

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

I've been reading several things, such as: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38), but I haven't had any luck trying these various solutions and I'm driving myself crazy.

The app runs fine locally.

Here are some details:

- I have Mysql and Mysql server installed
- The service is running (again everything works as expected locally)

Here is the [client] portion of my.cnf, which is located at /etc/mysql/

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I see some suggestions talking about mysqld, others mysql - I don't understand the difference.

Database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: wp_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: **Left out
  host: localhost
```

I just downloaded MySql today, so I am on 5.5, the latest build. *I'm running Linux.

Can someone please point me toward a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: This has been covered in other posts. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499035/ruby-on-rails-3-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-s

Comment: As I mentioned, I've seen a bunch of these solutions and nothing has worked. Server seems to be running. I have a socket in database.yml and changing to 127.0.0.1 just gives another error "Cannot connect to MySql on 127.0.0.1".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect locally, you should add `socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` inside the `development` config in your database.yml.

Also, make sure your RAILS_ENV is correct when running your app on AWS. If it is not set, then it should be `development`. But I'm not sure how you are starting your app.

Comment: Ok, so I added the socket line to my database.yml, and AWS sets the RAILS_ENV variable to production by default, so I changed that to "development". I've made progress.  I no longer get an "application failure" error page on AWS, now I get a Rails error page, but the page still complains of the "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)" error.

Comment: I am using Beanstalk on AWS to start the app.  "eb start". Handles pretty much everything I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be the specified socket path in your Gemfile might be wrong.

First, to find your socket file:

```
mysqladmin variables | grep socket
```

For me, this gives:

```
| socket  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Then, add this line `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`  to your config/database.yml in the socket field. See the below examples

**Example:**     `socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

## Development Mode

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: xxxx
  database: xxxx
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock #  this line
```

## Production Mode

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: xxxx
  database: xxxx
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock  #  this line
```

## Test Mode

```
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: xxxx
  database: xxxx
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock  #  this line
```