# db:migrate does not create tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Working with:

- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rails 4
- MySQL 5.6

Whenever I run "rake db:migrate" no tables are created in the database.

I have created a database and named it "simple_cms_development" and changed the development part of "database.yml" accordingly:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: simple_cms
  password: ruby
  timeout: 5000
```

I generated and model named "User" and edited "create_users.rb" to:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string "first_name", :limit => 25
      t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
      t.string "email", :default => "", :null => false
      t.string "password", :limit => 40
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I run "rake db:migrate" and there is no change to the tables within the database. When I run `SHOW TABLES;` in MySQL I get back "Empty set (0.00sec)". I don't even get "schema_migrations" table.

Any ideas what is going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `database.yml` is set up to use sqlite3, not mySQL. Yours is now this:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: simple_cms
  password: ruby
  timeout: 5000
```

You should probably be using the [mySQL2 gem](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2), and your `database.yml` should look something like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2 
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: your-password
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

According to [this StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499035/ruby-on-rails-3-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-s) you can get your socket by running

```
mysqladmin variables | grep socket
```

or if you have a password on your root:

```
mysqladmin password-here variables | grep socket`
```

If you want to use host and port instead of socket try this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2 
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: your-password
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
```

Here is a blog with instructions on how to set up mySQL with Rails 3.2, it might help with your Rails 4 issue: http://cicolink.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-3-with.html

Comment: Yeah you were right. mysql2 gem sorted everything. Ended up doing a fresh install of everything following these videos http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5S7vjN6GLc&list=PLcwklDOKWhc-4SOfwx71yEKzMHGw1BU_h

Installing mysql2 on Windows is a bit of mission.

Thanks very much for your help!