# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sockets

I have Rails 3 app on Justhost server. I am still working on it, but sometimes I get this error :

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)
```

I checked similair questions:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499035/ruby-on-rails-3-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-s)

I tried this command `mysqladmin variables | grep socket`

Get this error

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'ecotec11'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Don't understand how that could happen. Because I haven't changed ***database.yml*** file for long time.

I checked my databases are in good condition, users and passwords are the same.

I tried to restart server with `touch tmp/restart.txt` no luck in here!

Comment: Try just commenting it out in database.yml

Comment: try running mysqladmin with -user -password parameters.

Comment: @Baloo I commented out the socket line, and project is up again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reinstall mysql package to be enabled to set your configuration.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server --reinstall
```

If this doesn't allow you to reconfigure the package you can use

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server
```

Look on DigitalOcean how to configure your MySQL:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/a-basic-mysql-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem so i follow the steps from
http://sraji.wordpress.com/2011/05/18/problem-solved-for-mysql2error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmpmysql-sock-2-in-rails-3/

I added the socket:path into my database.yml file. Now it runs smoothly.
I hope this help someone.

cheers,

Answer (score 2):

For me worked following:

```
cd /usr/local/var/mysql
sudo rm -r xxxx-MacBook-Air.local.err
sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/var/mysql
sudo mysql.server start
```

Until now I dont know what causes problems with running mysql server. If I will find out I will let you know for sure :)

Cheers

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm. Thank you so much ;)

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem running `rake db:migrate` on the production server. Checking my database.yml file I had the correct path under the production settings, but I wasn't running migration under the appropriate environment.

So, running `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
cd /tmp <br/>
ln -s /opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
```