# Unable to start mysql in redmine

Tags: mysql, linux, redmine

Hi I'm unable to start my mysql and subversion using root as user.When im trying to start it by `./ctlscript.sh start mysql` it is showing that  mysql  `could not be started`.The same is happening in the case of subversion also.In logs its showing that

```
 error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/data/redmine/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)
error: [ pid=6349 thr=139977144923904 file=ext/common/agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1731 time=2014-09-29 12:54:58.7821 ]: [Client 23] Cannot checkout session. An error occured while starting up the preloader.
```

Can any one help?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499035/ruby-on-rails-3-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-s ?

Comment: No.This is not working. :(

Comment: (This question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow as it doesn't concern a programming problem.) Still, check your mysql log files. It seems the server can't start up for some reason. And if you don't find that reason, nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether your root user has the permission to start the mysql and other services.
If not please give the permissions using `CHMOD`

Comment: Yeah.Actually I have created 2 sudo root users and at that time.I changed all the permissions and then I forgot about that.

Comment: Be careful and avoid these sort of questions in Stack Overflow