# Rails S command won't work Error: Mysql Socket

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep running into this error each time I run the command rails s. I have had issues with installing gems, and running bundle from this directory. All I want to do is run my server on the designated port. I think I might not have the right credentials to run the server locally. The top level error I got is telling me that the MySQL server is not connecting. I have looked through a few other StackOverFlow threads and none of them have seem to help me. I have a Linux box, running Ubuntu 14.04. Please Help.

---

```
>  yonas@yonas:~/code/freelance/buh/impact$ rails s
    >         => Booting Thin
    >         => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
    >         => Call with -d to detach
    >         => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    >         Exiting
    >         /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in
    > `connect': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
    > '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in
    > `initialize'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in
    > `new'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in
    > `mysql2_connection'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in
    > `new_connection'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in
    > `checkout_new_connection'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in
    > `block (2 levels) in checkout'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in
    > `loop'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in
    > `block in checkout'
    >                 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in
    > `checkout'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in
    > `block in connection'
    >                 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in
    > `connection'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in
    > `retrieve_connection'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in
    > `retrieve_connection'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in
    > `connection'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:88:in
    > `block in <class:Railtie>'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
    > `instance_exec'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
    > `run'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in
    > `block in run_initializers'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
    > `each'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
    > `run_initializers'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in
    > `initialize!'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in
    > `method_missing'
    >                 from /home/yonas/code/freelance/HUB/impact-hub-seattle/config/environment.rb:5:in
    > `<top (required)>'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in
    > `require'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in
    > `block in require'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in
    > `load_dependency'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in
    > `require'
    >                 from /home/yonas/code/freelance/HUB/impact-hub-seattle/config.ru:3:in
    > `block in <main>'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in
    > `instance_eval'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in
    > `initialize'
    >                 from /home/yonas/code/freelance/HUB/impact-hub-seattle/config.ru:in `new'
    >                 from /home/yonas/code/freelance/HUB/impact-hub-seattle/config.ru:in
    > `<main>'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in
    > `parse_file'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in
    > `app'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in
    > `wrapped_app'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in
    > `start'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in
    > `block in <top (required)>'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in
    > `tap'
    >                 from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in
    > `<top (required)>'
    >                 from script/rails:6:in `require'
    >                 from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

---

```
    #
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: <%= ENV['HUB_DEV_DB'] %>
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['HUB_DEV_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['HUB_DEV_PASS'] %>
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: <%= ENV['HUB_TEST_DB'] %>
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['HUB_TEST_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['HUB_TEST_PASS'] %>
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: hub_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: hub123
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  adapter: mysql2
  username: root
  password: the_truth34
  socket: /tmp/sockets/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Looks like this might involve [the infamous "mysql.sock" error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5499035/1167750)... (from looking at this line: `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket > '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)`)

Comment: Went through that thread no dice. Might have done it wrong check out my config file above.

Comment: Hmm, and you're sure that MySQL is up and running, and that your `mysql.sock` path is correct in your config file?

Answer (score 0):

Rails is trying to connect to a MySQL database. Do you have it installed on your Linux server? What does your `config/database.yml` look like?

Check out Digital Ocean's guide on [Installing Rails, Apache, and MySQL on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-rails-apache-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-with-passenger).

Comment: Config file is up. I have a Linux box and I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. I'm just looking to get a local server up so I start developing locally.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I had to Purge Mysql, and then re Install it.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then I used the doc below to re install it. (Link below)

[Follow console steps very closely](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.digitalocean.com%2Fcommunity%2Ftutorials%2Fhow-to-use-mysql-with-your-ruby-on-rails-application-on-ubuntu-14-04&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGRgtKt5vQiK_nyg2_Xd4Dk9Ao9Tg)

When running this command:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Once you run this command you will be promoted to a few messages on your console, run the yes command when the console asks you if you want to set permissions now.