# RoR+Mysql (Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]
Rails 5.0.0.1
Server version: 5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 (Ubuntu)

database.yml

```
default: &default  
adapter: mysql2  
encoding: utf8  
pool: 5   
username: ****  
password: ****  
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

When I open the page with entities it works good, but when I am trying to add new record the error appeares:
`Puma caught this error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)

/home/ruby/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/lib/mysql2/client.rb:87:in connect

/home/ruby/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/lib/mysql2/client.rb:87:in initialize`

After I put rails server command it works again until I try to add new record.
How could I fix this bug?

Comment: hello, what is the output of `mysqladmin -u root status`?

Comment: mysqladmin -u root status -p
Enter password:
Uptime: 10017  Threads: 1  Questions: 6  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 107  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 26  Queries per second avg: 0.000

Comment: have you tried suggestions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499035/ruby-on-rails-3-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-s?

Comment: First of all, it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

This solves it:

```sh
ps -A|grep mysql

sudo pkill mysql

ps -A|grep mysqld

sudo pkill mysqld

sudo service mysql restart
```